# "in the lake" vs. "on the lake"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

What is the difference between "in the lake" and "on the lake", meaning-wise? It seems that "in" and "on" are different in terms of denoting a watery surface.

But also, could "on the lake" mean something is there around the perimeter of a certain lake?

Comment: Here is my personal tip: avoid memorizing the use of prepositions as patterns depending on what follows the preposition. The choice of preposition in a specific utterance, as I've observed, is the result of what comes before and after, both competing for the right choice, in the given context.

Comment: @ManishGiri I never meant to attack your answer. I fully agree that your original post was absolutely fine. I strongly disagree with the new, strict, and in my eyes pedantic application of attribution rules as SE has changed them. I picked your post as an example of why those rules (and their strict application!) is harmful. I _never_ meant to attack your style of attribution, I think it is **fine**!

Answer (score 4):

"In the lake"- inside the lake, below the surface.

> The food of twenty-six species of non-cichlid fishes ***in the Lake***
>   Victoria basin is described.
>
> [Source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-7998.1961.tb06080.x/abstract)<sup>(1)</sup>

"On the lake"- on the surface of the lake.

> Before you go boating **on Lake George**, please read the regulations and
>   rules - they are slightly different than other lakes in New York
>   State!
>
> Find all the resources you need to enjoy boating **on the lake**.
>
> [Source](http://www.lakegeorge.com/boating/)<sup>(2)</sup>

As for your last question:

> could "on the lake" mean something is there around the perimeter of a
>   certain lake?

the usage of "*on*" would  fit in certain contexts. As Jim suggests in the comments below, you *can* have a **cottage on the lake** where the cottage is **not** a house boat. But in my opinion, this is fairly debatable. I would rather use *"cottage by the lake"*.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>CORBET, P. S. (1961), THE FOOD OF NON-CICHLID FISHES IN THE LAKE VICTORIA BASIN, WITH REMARKS ON THEIR EVOLUTION AND ADAPTATION TO LACUSTRINE CONDITIONS. Proceedings of the Zoological Society of London, 136: 1–101. doi: 10.1111/j.1469-7998.1961.tb06080.x
<sup>(2)</sup>LakeGeorge.com

Comment: But I can have a cottage on the lake which certainly does not suggest that it's a house boat.

Comment: You can have a cottage **on** the lake, but it's also very debatable.

Comment: It's a pretty standard expression where I'm from.  This ngram shows "cottage on the lake" has many more occurrences than "cottage at the lake" even though there can be many more instances of cottages simply at the lake, i.e., those that are near the lake but don't have property that includes shoreline, than those that are actually "on the lake"   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cottage+on+the+lake%2Ccottage+at+the+lake&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccottage%20on%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccottage%20at%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0

Comment: If you mean to say a cottage that is at the perimeter of the lake, then I'm inclined to use **by** instead of **at**. Also, for this situation, _cottage **on** the lake_ seems to be used more frequently than _cottage **by** the lake_ very recently, as you can see [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cottage+on+the+lake%2Ccottage+at+the+lake%2C+cottage+by+the+lake&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccottage%20on%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccottage%20at%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccottage%20by%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: What do you think about the sentence - *food waste dumped in OR on the lake?*

Comment: Manish, we can certainly have a *[resort on the beach (Curacao)](http://www.usatoday.com/experience/beach/caribbean/best-summer-deals-in-the-caribbean/14150999/)*, no debate at all.

Comment: @MaulikV 1. Food waste is dumped **in/into** the lake, [not on](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dumped+in+the+lake%2Cdumped+on+the+lake&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdumped%20in%20the%20lake%3B%2Cc0). 2. You certainly can have a resort **on** the beach. Besides, I don't remember saying anything about a beach, so I don't see where a debate would arise from.

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up! What I meant was -*[cottage on the lake](http://www.gazettextra.com/20140820/alton_myron_bud_arneson_janesville_wi_1924_2014)* is fine. And, *on the lake* has many other uses, not necessarily denoting *surface.* The OP is concerned about whether *on* has to do with *surface*. The answer is yes but **not always**.

Comment: @MaulikV - "yes but not always" is better expressed as "sometimes" ;^)

Comment: If you like I can make the attribution source appear smaller, more discreet and more "quiet". Some of us should know by now that caps is synonymous with shouting...

Comment: @oerkelens "2) If my reference (which is exactly as the source wants it it be) is too ugly, feel free to edit it." I will gladly do so, if and when the poster agrees.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree that some of us should know things. Go ahead tell them! Please address the right people with your thinly veiled insults: [check here on "how to cite"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-7998.1961.tb06080.x/abstract)

Answer (score 3):

I'm talking about the usage of prepositions in the context of lake/water only.

The preposition *on* not *always* mean *on the surface* of the lake. This said, **you can have a house *on* the lake; you can dump garbage *on* the lake; and even can spend a beautiful day *on* the lake!** But yes, *on* refers to the surface also. You have *vessel* on the waters of oceans, you have *boating* on the lake.

On the other hand, using *in*, in most of the cases, means *inside* it. For instance, *...various aquatic species in the lake.* Note that if we want to emphasize the *depth*, we use *under*. *The cable under water is damaged*; *The wreckage of the ship is found under the sea.*

Comment: I'd prefer _you can dump garbage **in** the lake_ if the garbage is such that it generally sinks. If you are only dumping polystyrene then **on** the lake could work but _in the lake_ is the most common for anything that is not on the surface. Saying that I think even _they dumped oil in the lake_ would be preferred, even though oil floats on top of the water.

Comment: Maybe, because when you *throw*, you *throw* it *on* the lake and not *in*! But that's just a thought.

Comment: When something sinks, I throw it _in_ the lake. When something floats, I still throw it _in_ the lake, although there might be some room for _on_.